# Parametrized constructor in virtually inheriting abstract class

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I have a classical virtual inheritance diamond:

```
class A {
protected:
    A(const char *x) { ... }
}

class B: public virtual A {
protected:
    B(): A(NULL) { ... }
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

class C: public virtual A {
protected:
    C(): A(NULL) { ... }
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
}

class D: public B, public C {
public:
    D(const char *x): A(x) { ... }
    void foo();
    void bar();
}
```

I use NULL in `B` and `C` because as they're abstract classes, the `A` ctor will never be called in their constructurs. Is there a nicer way to do it, otherwise than specify `NULL` in the constructor or declare parameterless constructor in `A`? I want the constructor to be called with a parameter, therefore the `A() {}` ctor should be allowed only in abstract classes.

Comment: I can also define some AbstractPlaceholder and have this as `A(const AbstractPlaceholder &ap) { assert(false); }` - this is probably the best, but maybe someone knows yet better solution that would allow the A to not know that it will be virtually inherited.

Comment: "as they're abstract classes, the A ctor will never be called in their constructurs." How's that?

Comment: Very interesting. I suppose the compiler has no reason to know whether or not `B` can be instantiated, and so `B`'s constructor *has* to call a constructor for its `A` subobject, even if that subobject is virtual and the real constructor call may be replaced. Morally, the thing we'd want is for `A` to have a pure-virtual constructor, `virtual A() = 0;`, which could be used by virtual, abstract derived classes.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, what's wrong with that quote? When using virtual inheritance, only the most derived class (here `D`) initializes the virtually inherited ones (here `A`), and all other initializations of `A` (here in `B` and `C`) are ignored.

Comment: My last solution also has a problem I have found - if A has field of reference type (this must be assigned in the constructor), I have to somehow fool it (currently I don't know how).

Comment: Hmm, so the solution for the reference initialization could be just to pass `*(new Foo())`, as with never calling it in the runtime there is no memory leak. However, if Foo has parametric constructor, there may be the need to either pass dummy arguments or add `Foo(const AbstractPlaceholder &)` ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this as the rigth answer probably does not exist. IMO the best workaround is the

```
struct AbstractPlaceholder {
    AbstractPlaceholder() {
        assert(false);
    }
};

class A {
protected:
    A(const AbstractPlaceholder &ap) {}
    A(const char *x) { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `A` to:

```
class A {
private:
    A() {};
    friend class B;
    friend class C;
protected:
    A(const char *x) { }
};
```

And then `B(): A() {}` and `C(): A() {}` would work, yet `D(const char*): A() {}` won't. But this is really awkward. I'd stick with the `NULL` you're using at the moment.

This is indeed an interesting case, though. I could think of no technical reason why you'd *have* to specify a constructor for `A` in `B` and `C` given they'll never be created, and whoever inherits them is going to initialize `A` anyway.

Comment: "They'll never be created"?!?!

Comment: I wasn't sure how to put that... They are abstract, so there will be no `new C`. How should this be better phrased?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify **default argument** in `A(const char*)`

```
class A {
protected:
    A(const char *x = 0) { ... }
                    ^^^^
};
```

However, this will also allow `D` to avoid `A()`.

Comment: Yes, that's true - this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of your approach would be

```
class A {
protected:
    A(const char *x = NULL) {
      assert(x && "A mustn't be default constructed!");
    }
};
```

Thereby adding a more meaningful diagnostic.

---

However, you may want to explicitly allow `x` to be `NULL` (as a legal construction via `C`), then you could use a `Maybe` type.

```
template <typename T> class Maybe {
  T const t; // must be default constructible!
  bool const invalid;
  public:
    Maybe() : t(), invalid(true) {}
    Maybe(T t) : t(t), invalid(false) {}
    bool nothing() const {
      return invalid;
    }
    T just() const {
      assert(!invalid);
      return t;
    }
};
```

Then you can change your constructor to

```
A::A(Maybe<const char*> mx) {
  // either
  assert(!mx.nothing());
  // or
  mx.just();
}
```